# How to conditionally postfix a variable?

Tags: ansible

For now I  am using this option to set specific bundle value for patching via include_vars.
It is working fine, the problem is that every month I have to change all included variables files (*bundle.yml*).

```yaml
- name: Setting OS specific bundle variable
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "vars/{{ ansible_distribution }}_{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}/bundle.yml"
        - "vars/default.yml"
```

So my goal is to use just one variable: `bundle` in the main playbook and then based on OS condition I will change this variable value on the fly.
Basicly I only need to change the `bundle` string for RH6 to append `ELS`.

Example: the goal is to set `bundle` to `1Q2023ELS` for RH6

```yaml
vars:
  bundle: 1Q2023

tasks:
  - name: set_bundle for RH6
    set_fact:
      bundle: bundle+'ELS'
    when: ansible_distribution == "RedHat" and ansible_distribution_major_version == 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html) your variable in the `set_fact` task.
You should also prefer the concatenation operator — `~`, rather than the addition operator — `+`.
As pointed in the documentation:

> Usually the objects are numbers, but if both are strings or lists, you can concatenate them this way. This, however, is not the preferred way to concatenate strings! For string concatenation, have a look-see at the `~` operator.

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#math*</sup>

Also note that you can use a list in the `when` clause, [when the conditions are logical `and`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts).

So, your task ends up being:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    bundle: "{{ bundle ~ 'ELS' }}"
  when: 
    - ansible_distribution == "RedHat"
    - ansible_distribution_major_version == 6
```

Comment: Bravo ! This is it what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Put the logic into the *group_vars*. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/bundle.yml
bundle_ext:
  RedHat:
    '5': ELS
    '6': ELS
    '7': ELS
  Ubuntu:
    '18': LTS
    '20': LTS
    '22': LTS

bundle: "{{ bundle_ver ~
            bundle_ext[ansible_distribution][ansible_distribution_major_version] }}"
```

Then the play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    bundle_ver: 1Q2023

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: distribution
    - debug:
       var: bundle
```

gives, for example,

```yaml
  bundle: 1Q2023LTS
```